# R- Error of "Non-conformable argument"

Tags: r

I want to get predicted probabilities from an ordered logit model.

Code:

```
library(plyr)
library(forcats)
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

zz <- "DV IV1 IV2  year
1          51         0      1987
2          49         1     1988  
3          47         0      1990
5          50         0      1991
5          54         1      1992
1          23         0      1993
3          15         0      1994"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
Data <- mutate(Data, DV=as.ordered(DV))

order <- polr(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2 + factor(year), data=Data,
           method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE)
```

After running this, a warning is shown:

```
Warning message:
In polr(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1 * IV2 + factor(year), data = Data,  :
 design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs
```

Then I run:

```
colMeans(predict(order, type="probs", 
             newdata=mutate(Data, IV2=1, IV1=50)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

R responds:

```
Error in X %*% object$coefficients : non-conformable arguments
```

I tried the linear model without "factor(year)", then error was gone. But "factor(year)" is supposed to be included in the model to address time-series. How can I include it without any error of "non-conformable arguments"?

Comment: The first warning message says that `polr` has dropped a column (in this case `year`). This causes the problem later when you are trying to predict using that variable.

Comment: So how can I prevent polr from dropping the column?

Comment: Maybe you can try out an alternative to `polr`? See [here](http://dwoll.de/rexrepos/posts/regressionOrdinal.html).